# In Java, Null Pointer Exception when trying to write to a Named Pipe

Tags: java, linux, nullpointerexception

I am new to Java and I don't understand how to write to named pipe. I would like to have my Java to read data from one pipe, do some transformations, and then write to another pipe.

This is on Linux. I set up the pipes without a problem, and I have not had errors regarding the pipes.

For a long time I was getting a Null Pointer Exception on this line:

writePipe.write(m);

I was using a FileOutputStream for the 'writePipe'. But now I have switched to a PrintWriter.

I am using 2 terminal windows to test my code. I run my app in one terminal, and then in the other, I will write this message to the pipe:

```
echo "Ankanth, expect messages like this!" > api-sends-messages-to-nlp
```

Up until 15 minutes ago, this would be read correctly, but then, when my app tried to write the message back, I got a Null Pointer Exception. Now the Null Pointer Exception does not appear until I read from the pipe:

```
cat nlp-sends-messages-to-api
```

At which point I see:

```
We just received this message: 
Ank, expect messages like this!
We got a message in the main loop()!
Now we will write to the pipe.
error in writeMessage java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My "Api" class handles reading and writing to the pipes:

```
public class Api {

// Connect to the named pipe                                                                                                                             
public BufferedReader readPipe = null;
public PrintWriter writePipe = null;


Api() {
    try {
        this.readPipe = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/rollio/api-sends-messages-to-nlp"));
        this.writePipe = new PrintWriter((new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/home/rollio/nlp-sends-messages-to-api"))));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error in Api constructor " + e);
    }
}


public String readMessage() throws Exception {
    try {
        // Read response from pipe                                                                                                                       
        String message = readPipe.readLine();
        System.out.println("We just received this message: ");
        System.out.println(message);
        return message;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error in readMessage " + e);
        throw new Exception("error in readMessage " + e);
    }
}

    public void writeMessage(String message) throws Exception {
    try {
        // Write request to the pipe                                                                                                                     
        String m = message.concat(" ...said the awesome NLP app!!!! Hell yeah!!!!!");
        System.out.println("Now we will write to the pipe.");
        if (m==null)
            m="";
        writePipe.println("This next line is the message: ");
        writePipe.println(m);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error in writeMessage " + e);
        throw new Exception("error in writeMessage " + e);
    }
}
```

The above runs forever in a while loop() started in main:

```
   public static void main(String...args){
        try {
            Api rw = new Api();
            while (true) {
                String message = rw.readMessage();
                // something magic happens and Ankanth transforms the message                                                                           
                System.out.println("We got a message in the main loop()!");
                rw.writeMessage(message);
    }

                }

    catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    }
```

It appears that this is the line that throws the Null Pointer Exception:

```
writePipe.println(m);
```

The path to the pipe is correct, so what would the problem be?

UPDATE:

Okay, if I change the read method like this:

```
public String readMessage() throws Exception {
    try {
        // Read response from pipe                                                                                                                       
        String message = readPipe.readLine();
        System.out.println("We just received this message: ");
        System.out.println(message);
        return message;
    }
```

The 2 printlns give me:

```
We just received this message: 
null
```

But why would the message be null? I write to the pipe from a terminal, like this:

```
echo "expect messages like this!" > api-sends-messages-to-nlp
```

The app "hears" something because this line returns something:

```
readPipe.readLine();
```

But why does it return "null"? Why doesn't it return what was written to the pipe?

UPDATE AGAIN:

[edits]

So, from the terminal, I use "echo" to do 2 writes to the app, and then I use "cat" to read from it:

echo "Ankanth, expect messages like this!" > api-sends-messages-to-nlp

echo "Ankanth, expect messages like this!" > api-sends-messages-to-nlp

cat nlp-sends-messages-to-api

I get:

```
We just received this message: 
Ankanth, expect messages like this!
We got a message in the main loop()!
Now we will write to the pipe.

We just received this message: 
Ankanth, expect messages like this!
We got a message in the main loop()!
Now we will write to the pipe.

We just received this message: 
null
We got a message in the main loop()!
error in writeMessage java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.rollioapp.nlp.Api.writeMessage(Api.java:49)
    at com.rollioapp.nlp.Main.main(Main.java:41)
java.lang.Exception: error in writeMessage
```

There is evidence of a 3rd write, even though I only did 2 writes.

Line 49 is:

```
        String m = message.concat(" ...said the awesome NLP app!!!! Hell yeah!!!!!");
```

Comment: You state, `"The path to the pipe is correct, so what would the problem be?"` -- how do you know this for a fact? Have you tested this in some way that you know the path works? I just want to give a general warning that until you've solved your error, don't assume that anything is correct unless it is proven correct by testing.

Comment: I can "ls /path/to/pipe" from the terminal window. Does Java read an absolute path?

Comment: As I explained above: "I was using a FileOutputStream for the 'writePipe'. But now I have switched to a PrintWriter." So the "write" became a "println".

Comment: I see. But why change when you haven't fixed the NPE? And many file type NPE's are due to an incorrect path.

Comment: I changed it because I thought the class I was using was the wrong one. I am new to Java and I have no idea if a FileOutputStream is better or worse than a PrintWriter.

Comment: "many file type NPE's are due to an incorrect path". So, how would I test that?

Comment: I must correct myself, the NPE often happens when reading a file that doesn't exist. Can you change all your catch blocks. Clean them up by making them post the full stacktrace, i.e., `e.printStackTrace()`. Let's have the stacktrace tell us *exactly* what line is throwing the exception.

Comment: I notice that if I do 2 writes, before I do a read, the first few writes seem to work, but then there is evidence of a 3rd write, which I did not trigger, and it is the 3rd write that seems to trigger an error. Could that have something to do with the loop I'm in? Or is there an EOF that I need to watch for?

Comment: [BufferedReader API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--). It returns `null` at the end of a File. Search this site to see how to  read correctly with a BufferedReader.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you got an exception in the constructor, ignored it, or didn't know about it, and proceeded as thought it hadn't happened.

Don't write code like this. The constructor should *throw* the exception, not catch it. Then the rest of the code can't execute.

Comment: If I get an error in the Api constructor, shouldn't I get "error in Api constructor" printed out in the terminal?

Comment: Also, if I got an exception in the constructor, why do I see this line printed out in the terminal? System.out.println("We got a message in the main loop()!");

Comment: As I said above, the code does print out "Now we will write to the pipe" suggesting that we get all the way to the line with 
writePipe.println(m);
before an exception is thrown.